# How to Recurse to print

Tags: java, recursion

Here is the question:

Write a recursive void method that has one parameter which is an integer and that writes to the screen the number of asterisks “*” given by the argument. The output should be all in one line. Assume that the argument is positive.

It is not a homework or assignment. Just a question in the slides with no answers...

I just don't know how to do it. I am a noob in this

here is my code and what i know

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ez {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String str = input.nextLine();
        String words[] = str.split("\\s");
        int length = words.length;
        int clength = str.length();
        
        System.out.println(length);
        System.out.println(clength);
        
        
    }

    public static void asterisksCounter (int n) {
        
    }
    }
```

Any big brains that know how to solve this question?
Thank you :)

Comment: void write(int n) { if (n <= 0) return; System.out.print("*"); write(n - 1); } System.out.println("");

Comment: @NomadMaker Isn't this please to ask questions about programming so you can understand it...

Comment: Also give the question a reasonable title. I think there is a lot of material out explaining how recursion works. Basically your example is a simple "count down" problem.

Comment: Post your attempt and ask for help. Don't just ask how to do it. And upvote when you get help. Thank you

Comment: [Nishit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2655988/nishit) has already given the solution. All you have to do is configure your inputs to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this is not a place to just ask a question and get an answer, since you mentioned that you have no idea how recursion works, giving you the code.

```
static void write(int n){
            if(n == 0){
                return;
            }
            System.out.print("*");
            write(n-1);
        }
```

General expectation is for the OP to try the problem by themselves, inform the community of the effort they put in and where exactly they are stuck. We would have been happier to help you after seeing some code from your side in the write() method.

Comment: I would recommend an assert to ensure the initial input is not negative...

Comment: @NavidMitchell OP did mention in the question that we can assume 'n' to be positive.

Comment: Change the initial check to '(n <= 0)' and you cover the possibility of a negative n.